# Accessing top master page properties in a nested master page code behind

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have a nested master page that has its own master page. The parent master page has a property defined in its code behind.

```
  Public ReadOnly Property SelectedPage() As String
    Get
      Return _selectedPage
    End Get
  End Property
```

How can I reference the parent master page's property from within either the child master page's code behind Page_Load or aspx template page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VB.Net:

```
DirectCast(Master, MyMastPageType).SelectedPage
```

C#:

```
((MyMastPageType)Master).SelectedPage
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.master.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   MyDemoMaster m = Master as MyDemoMaster;
>   m.MyProperty = "My button text";
> }
> ```

See:

- [**How to access controls inside a
  nested master page?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874357/how-to-access-controls-inside-a-nested-master-page-why-does-it-behave-differentl)
- [**The right way of accessing Master
  page properties from a child page**](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2007/10/right-way-of-accessing-master-page.html)

Comment: Great links that explain the entire process beautifully +1

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
DirectCast(MyMastPageType, Master).SelectedPage
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I use

```
MasterPage tmp = this.Master;
while (tmp.Master != null)
{
    tmp = tmp.Master;
}
```